# Memory Leaks in pop() for A Queue

Tags: c, memory-leaks

My **pop** function does not seem to work as it should.  Basically, my **queue** has a pointer to the first and last elements.

My **pop** functions starts by freeing the first element and assigning it to **NULL**.

Then it uses the pointer **curr** to get to the next element each time until it find a **NULL**.

Finally, my the first pointer in my queue gets assigned to **prev**, which was pointing to the last element before my **curr** reached null.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Queue {
    struct Node* first;
    struct Node* last;
};

struct Node {
    Item val;
    struct Node* next;
};


void initQueue (struct Queue **queue){
    (*queue) = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    (*queue)->first = NULL;
    (*queue)->last = NULL;
}

struct Node* createNewNode(){
    struct Node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}



void push (Item val, struct Queue *queue){
    struct Node* newNode = createNewNode();
    newNode->val = val;


    if(queue->first == NULL){
        queue->first = newNode;
        queue->last = newNode;
    }

    else{
        newNode->next = queue->last;
        queue->last = newNode;
    }
}

void pop(struct Queue *queue){

    struct Node* curr = queue->last;
    struct Node* prev = queue->last;


    free(queue->first);
    queue->first = NULL;

    while(curr != NULL){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    queue->first = prev;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To pop from the front of the list, simply have `first` point to `first->next`.

```
void pop(struct Queue *queue)
{
    if (NULL != queue->first) {
        struct Node *first = queue->first;
        // Update first ptr
        queue->first = queue->first->next;
        free(first);
        // Only need to update tail if list is empty
        if (NULL == queue->first) {
            queue->last = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment it looks like you aren't seeing what I'm doing, so here's an example.

Assume the queue looks like this:

`queue->first`
↓
A → B → C → D ← `queue->last`

First, make a temporary pointer and have it point to `queue->first`. Then move `queue->first` so that it points to `queue->first->next`. The list now looks like:

`queue->first`
        ↓
A → B → C → D ← `queue->last`
↑
`first` (temp var)

Then, delete the temp var and the list is:

`queue->first`
↓
B → C → D ← `queue->last`

**EDIT 2** I also notice your `push` function is incorrect. In a queue, you add new items to the end of the list and take items from the front (FIFO - First In First Out). Like people lining up to see a show. The *first* person to get there and get in line will be the first to enter the theater. And the *last* person to arrive goes to the back of the line. So `push` should be:

```
void push (Item val, struct Queue *queue){
    struct Node* newNode = createNewNode();
    newNode->val = val;

    if(queue->first == NULL) {
        queue->first = newNode;
        queue->last = newNode;
    }
    else{
        queue->last->next = newNode;  // Add to END of list
        queue->last = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not adjust the pointers after it frees the memory location that **queue->first** was pointing to. For example, once you **free(first)**, **queue->first** is no longer pointing to any element. Instead, the previous element should be now point to by **queue->first**.

Comment: @M.S I re-assign it on the line _before_ the free.

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: In a queue, the first element is the first element that enters the queue and leaves the queue. So, queue->first->next always points to null, since it is the first element in the queue. The steps you described in your solution would work for a stack, but not for a queue. In other words, in your example, D should be deleted from the queue instead of A.

Comment: From Wikipedia, operations in a queue are _addition of entities to the **rear** terminal position, known as enqueue, and removal of entities from the **front** terminal position, known as dequeue_. I've updated my answer to show how your `push` should also be changed.